# What criteria are used to sort symbols?

Tags: javascript, ascii

I need to sort a list of symbols.

By some empirical evidence to sample, it seems to me that the sort order, at least on JavaScript, is the decimal ASCII value of symbols ("!"=33, "$"=36, "&"=38). I am wrong? If not, is it a correct/standard criteria (followed by other programming languages)?

```html
<script>
function go() {
  var MyArray = ["C", "B", "A", 3, 1, 2, "*", "&", "!", "$"];
  MyArray.sort();
  alert(MyArray);
}
</script>
<button onclick="go()">SORT</button>
```

Comment: Yup, but more accurately Unicode point.

Comment: It is definitely based on character set comparisons. See also the `.localeCompare()` function on the String protoytpe.

Comment: And yes, most languages value (and thereby sort) characters (symbols are characters, too) based on their decimal values in the character set.